# AzCopy Blob Storage List Containers Permission Denied

Tags: azure-devops, azure-blob-storage, azcopy

I'm using **RBAC** to perform a blob copy operation: the service principal which azcopy is logged in as has the Storage Blob Data Contributor role for my subscription (listed as a requirement [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-authorize-azure-active-directory))... however, I get a permission denied exception as follows:

[image: Failure output]

As you can see, the failing operation is to list the storage account containers (line 68 and 74)

I appreciate this isn't easy to debug without further info... but I'm pretty stumped, so if anyone has had a similar issue, I'd be very grateful for any observations/past experiences :)

**Edit**: please note that azcopy reports successful authentication:

```
INFO: SPN Auth via secret succeeded.
INFO: Scanning...
INFO: Authenticating to destination using Azure AD
INFO: Authenticating to source using Azure AD
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this in the API docs:

[image]

Now, what's interesting here is that my service principal already had Owner permission on the subscription (infra pipeline stands up resources and assigns permissions etc.) - so I initially discounted this from being the issue... then, on a hunch, I assigned the Storage Blob Data Owner role *directly* on the storage account... and **Voila - it worked!!**